# Are unique_prts allowed to implicitly convert their containing type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

Can somebody explain my why my `factory` function is correct? Is `unique_ptr` doing dynamic casts by default? Why does the return type not have to be the same as the `factory` function type?

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Animal
{
  virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "(...)" << std::endl; }
};

struct Cat : public Animal
{
  virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "Meaw!" << std::endl; }
};

struct Dog: public Animal
{
  virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "Woof!" << std::endl; }
};

struct ConfusedCat : public Cat
{
  virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "Moooooh!" << std::endl; }
};

// Why is this factory function allowed like this?
std::unique_ptr<Animal> factory(const int i)
{
  if (i == 1)
    return std::unique_ptr<Cat>(new Cat());
  else if (i == 2)
    return std::unique_ptr<ConfusedCat>(new ConfusedCat());
  else if (i == 3)
    return std::unique_ptr<Dog>(new Dog());
  else
    return std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal());
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    auto animal0 = factory(0);
    auto animal1 = factory(1);
    auto animal2 = factory(2);
    auto animal3 = factory(3);

    animal0->makeSound();
    animal1->makeSound();
    animal2->makeSound();
    animal3->makeSound();
  }
  catch ( std::exception &e )
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ derived to public base pointer conversion is implicit, no cast is required.

The same holds true for all standard and boost smart pointers.

See overload 6 on [`std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr):

> std::unique_ptr<Derived> is implicitly convertible to std::unique_ptr<Base> through the overload (6)

Comment: So that means that in the `return unique_ptr< ... >` I could put whichever parent class of the same type that is in between the return type and the actual type? So in case of the `ConfusedCat` I could put `<ConfusedCat>`, `<Cat>` and `<Animal>` and the code is 100% equivalent?

Comment: Also, [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) says it explicitly, "If T is derived class of some base B, then std::unique_ptr<T> is implicitly convertible to std::unique_ptr<B>."